# Apple Watch app does not localize

Tags: localization, apple-watch

I have set up interface.storyboard strings for German, French, Spanish, and Simplified Chinese.  I download the iOS app and it loads to the watch. I then set the watch language to German, for example.  But the UI is still in English.

Here are the interface.storyboard strings:

```
    /* Class = "WKInterfaceButton"; title = "Start Timer"; ObjectID = "1oP-Ed-sIA"; */
"1oP-Ed-sIA.title" = "Timer starten";

/* Class = "WKInterfaceButton"; title = "0:30"; ObjectID = "Kti-O4-Ky6"; */
"Kti-O4-Ky6.title" = "0:30";

/* Class = "WKInterfaceDate"; format = " h:mm:ss a"; ObjectID = "P50-YW-9sa"; */
"P50-YW-9sa.format" = " h:mm:ss a";

/* Class = "WKInterfaceButton"; title = "0:15"; ObjectID = "QLq-vX-zHG"; */
"QLq-vX-zHG.title" = "0:15";

/* Class = "WKInterfaceButton"; title = "Do Not Disturb"; ObjectID = "Zku-u8-rhy"; */
"Zku-u8-rhy.title" = "Bitte nicht stören";

/* Class = "WKInterfaceButton"; title = "Stop Timer"; ObjectID = "afW-nF-dFL"; */
"afW-nF-dFL.title" = "Stoppuhr";

/* Class = "WKInterfaceButton"; title = "0:60"; ObjectID = "tDV-Bi-XDn"; */
"tDV-Bi-XDn.title" = "0:60";
```

Here is the watch screenshot:

[image: apple watch screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

I found out that BOTH the watch target AND the watch extension target have to be selected under the localized strings setting "Target Membership."  I do not know why, since supposedly the extension only needs to be localized if there is code that affects the UI, not just the storyboard. But doing this does localize the watch UI.

[image: interface.storyboard strings]

Comment: Seems to me this is the correct solution as of watchOS 6.2. You should mark it as such.